# Can you upgrade the SSD of an M1 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook, upgrade, laptop-repair, macbook-air

Is there a non-manufacturer way to upgrade the SSD storage of a M1 MacBook Air (2020)?

If so, how large?

Answer (score 8):

### No, you can’t.

The chips for the SSD are soldered on the motherboard. This is the case for any/all MacBooks since 2018 or 2019.

That said, if you are *extremely* skilled in component level tinkering, then you *might* attempt the “advice” in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1816257/167207). But doing this is not for the faint of heart and will definitely void your warranty and risks damaging your MacBook. I do not advise you take that advice seriously.

Comment: Isn't there some proprietary integration with the Secure Enclave that would prevent this from working?

Answer (score -4):

Yes. It is possible. To the best of my knowledge, to no larger than 2 TB with the 2020 MacBook Air.

As a high level outline of the work:

1. You'll probably need a Time Machine backup on an external drive, and preferably making a full copy of your machine on a similar hardware configuration as the to-be-upgraded machine so as to verify the Time Machine backup is perfect.
2. Log out, and erase your computer as you will not be able to easily do that once the SSD chips are off your motherboard
3. Open the Mac, and remove the SSD chips.
4. Solder the new wafers on the mother board.
5. Re-flash the computer with Apple's own DFU tool.
6. Activate the machine by logging into your iCloud and entering your old password.
7. Connected to WiFi,and power, install MacOS.
8. Restore your data from the external-drive Time Machine backup.
9. Done!

Source and video guide: A reliable tutorial that gives a step-by-step guide to a person of ordinary skill in the art sufficient guidance is one from Robert Lindenau', German computer engineer/technicians tutorial from his YouTube channel here:

[MacBook Pro M1 (A2338) SSD Upgrade 256GB to 2TB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9C0seGPu50)

I supplied this guide to a friend to collaboratively achieve the same, and we managed to upgrade a 2020 MacBook Air from 512 GB to 2 TB.

Comment: “Open the Mac, and remove the SSD chips.“ No, it is not possible for normal human beings who expect to just open it up, pop out the old SSD and put in a new SSD. Ripping out the NAND chips and soldering in new NAND chips is not what normal/non-engineers do. “…guide to a person of ordinary skill in the art sufficient guidance…” Utter nonsense.

Comment: Since this is self answered, is this spam? How are you connected to the “tutorial” video creator? This is horribly dangerous advice.

Comment: There are a few similar mods online… but, & it's a big but [so to speak] the chances of your average consumer being up to the task are so close to nil as to be irrelevant.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. A normal consumer with no electronics skills will run a very high risk of destroying the Macbook.

Comment: PS: “Re-flash the computer with Apple's own DFU tool.” This is utterly not something most people know how to do.

Comment: Lots of h8s but this remains a valid answer, even if preponderant for most people

Comment: If you can't do it yourself, at least knowing it is possible to a trained electronics person, you can look for people that would do it for you.